# Aws elastic beanstalk 'try add execution permission' prebuild hooks error

Tags: bash, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, hook

My eb-engine.log file says the following:

```
2022/12/02 09:06:55.661307 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks
2022/12/02 09:06:55.661326 [INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/prebuild/
2022/12/02 09:06:55.661362 [INFO] Following scripts will be executed in order: [00_npm_install.sh]
2022/12/02 09:06:55.661368 [INFO] Try add execution permission
2022/12/02 09:06:55.661375 [INFO] Running script: .platform/hooks/prebuild/00_npm_install.sh
2022/12/02 09:07:19.325093 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks]. Stop running the command. Error: Command .platform/hooks/prebuild/00_npm_install.sh failed with error exit status 244.
```

I **do** have permissions set up for the file(s) in question:

```
$ git ls-files -s .platform
100755 e8c201d7464dcf52ae874bb106de1a0da6a7bd20 0       .platform/confighooks/prebuild/00_npm_install.sh
100755 e8c201d7464dcf52ae874bb106de1a0da6a7bd20 0       .platform/hooks/prebuild/00_npm_install.sh
100644 7744deea7dfdafe4f584e01991cb6e80ee3079b9 0       .platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf
```

But this error occurs anyway ever since I committed (using github desktop) and pushed from a new device, which was an update that did not tweak my files. Before that commit & push, the output was the following:

```
2022/11/30 18:56:18.539468 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks
2022/11/30 18:56:18.539488 [INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/prebuild/
2022/11/30 18:56:18.539521 [INFO] Following scripts will be executed in order: [00_npm_install.sh]
2022/11/30 18:56:18.539527 [INFO] Try add execution permission
2022/11/30 18:56:18.539535 [INFO] Adding execute mode to file, original mode is 436
2022/11/30 18:56:18.539543 [INFO] Running script: .platform/hooks/prebuild/00_npm_install.sh
2022/11/30 18:56:32.415210 [INFO] Finished running scripts in /var/app/staging/.platform/hooks/prebuild
```

Does anyone know what could have changed or how to fix this?

Comment: `error exit status 244` is downright weird: exit statuses (stati?) are normally 0, 1, 2, etc., except for "killed by signal" which tends to be 128+signal-number. Given this error, look in the `.sh` script it points out to see what might produce such an odd status. In any case it's not from Git, which sticks with the above and the occasional 125 through 127 (`git bisect`).

Comment: @torek the file simply contains the following:  
`#!/bin/bash
cd /var/app/staging
sudo -u webapp npm install sharp`

Comment: OK, so, the exit status is coming from `npm install` (passed through by webapp) or from `webapp` itself, probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out something was wrong with my configuration of EB, it later also stopped giving me logs when I requested them. I set up some new configuration and after the environment was rebuilt, everything worked again.